# urxvt: scroll just one line

Tags: urxvt

I can scroll a chunk of output with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> (or <kbd>PageDown</kbd>), but is there a way to scroll just one line up and down? Often, you'd like to read something that is small enough to fit in one screen, but the scrolling is so heavy handed it is impossible to get the whole text chunk within one screen anyway!

Comment: I take it you don't want to use the [scrollbar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode#Scrollbar)?

Comment: Good point, forgot to say that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use *keysym + command* in my ~/.Xresources to scroll one line up with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> and one line down with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> :

```
.....................
URxvt*scrollBar:false
URxvt*scrollBar_right: false
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down: command:\033]721;1\007
```

Comment: Wonderful, works great!

Comment: Which docs should I check to find out something like this just by myself? Or what other sequences I could have as commands?

Comment: @Mr.Goferito - just google for `xresources` & `urxvt` and follow the links... [Here's a good place to start](https://www.askapache.com/linux/rxvt-xresources/)