# keybinding in xterm to shift one line up using shift+up

Tags: xterm

follow [urxvt: scroll just one line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44756/urxvt-scroll-just-one-line)

How can we set keybindings so that shift+up can scroll one line up in xterm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [X resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources) documented in the [XTerm man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm), particularly the "ACTIONS" section about 80% of the way down.

Create a file `~/.Xresources` and put in it:

```
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \
    Shift <Key>Up: scroll-back(1) \n\
    Shift <Key>Down: scroll-forw(1)
```

"Translations" is the base Xt library's name for key and mouse bindings. This sets bindings for the VT100 (terminal emulation) component of XTerm, overriding any existing bindings and setting Shift-Up to scroll up (or "back") one line, and Shift-Down to scroll down ("forw"ard) one line. We're making one long line so we're using backslashes at the end to mark continuation.

As with any use of `.Xresources`, you will need either to have the `XENVIRONMENT` variable set pointing to the right place, or use [`xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xrdb) to load the file into the resource manager explicitly.

Comment: Actually, `XAPPLRESDIR` is preferable to `XENVIRONMENT`.  The former lets you configure regular app-defaults files in your own directory, the latter forces everything into a single file.  `xrdb` ... is like the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Horner's answer is close, but overlooks a detail:

```
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \
    Shift <Key>Up: scroll-back(1) \n\
    Shift <Key>Down: scroll-forw(1)
```

uses the default units for scrolling.  To ensure that you get *lines*, you need to add a parameter:

```
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \
    Shift <Key>Up: scroll-back(1,line) \n\
    Shift <Key>Down: scroll-forw(1,line)
```

The manual page mentions the units in describing [`scroll-back`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:scroll-back) and [`scroll-forw`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:scroll-forw), but does not mention in that paragraph that the default is set by another resource, [**`scrollLines`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:scrollLines):

```
   scrollLines (class ScrollLines)
           Specifies  the number of lines that the scroll-back and scroll-
           forw actions should use as a default.  The default value is 1.
```