# Xresources / Xdefaults: Period or Asterisk?

Tags: rxvt, x-resources

I've just switched from *xfce4-terminal* to *rxvt-unicode* and I've been reading a lot of **.Xresources** and **.Xdefaults** files, piecing things together to create my own. My googling skills have left me with a number of unanswered questions; one of which is:

Is there a difference between `URxvt.font` and `URxvt*font`?

I have seen a number of variations, for example, [the answer for this questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44756/urxvt-scroll-just-one-line) uses a asterisk in one line and periods in another.

```
URxvt*scrollBar:false
URxvt*scrollBar_right: false
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down: command:\033]721;1\007`
```

Does that mean it doesn't matter or that it matters for some setting and not others? I'm hoping understanding the differences, if there are any, will help with the settings I can't get to work.

Comment: Both the answers here address this specific point: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216723/xterm-or-xterm-in-configuration-file

Comment: @jasonwryan, thank you for the link. I will spend some time with the X(7)manual.

Answer (score 8):

This is explained in the X manual (`man 7 X`):

> When an application looks for the value of a resource, it specifies a
>          complete path in the hierarchy, with both class and instance names.
>          However, resource values are usually given with only partially
>          specified names and classes, using pattern matching constructs.  **An
>          asterisk (`*`) is a loose binding and is used to represent any number of
>          intervening components, including none.  A period (`.`) is a tight
>          binding and is used to separate immediately adjacent components.**

This means that

```
URxvt*scrollBar:false
```

happens to be the same as

```
URxvt.scrollBar:false
```

since there is no intermediate component between `URxvt` and the `scrollBar` component (if I read the `urxvt` manual correctly).

However,

```
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
```

could probably be written

```
URxvt*Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
```

to bypass that intervening `keysym` component.  This will also set any other `Shift-Up` resource for the `URxvt` class though, if there are any other.

```
*Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
```

would set that resource for *all* X classes.

Asterisk works like a "globbing character", like `*` does for names in the shell, but for X resource names. Also, I believe you can't place a dot in the middle of a component name, so the analogy doesn't go all the way.